# Raspberry PI config.txt gets recreated and the custom modifications ignored

Tags: raspbian, config.txt

I have encountered a similar problem to;
 [Can't Access TTY: Job Control Turned Off](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19561/cant-access-tty-job-control-turned-off)

I followed the solution by adding `avoid_safe_mode=1` to `config.txt` but somehow the `config.txt` gets recreated and the modified one is ignored. What could be the problem and what's the solution of going about it.

Comment: This is pretty much impossible. Sounds like you didn't eject the card reader safely or didn't save the file properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your SDCard as it is worn out. If you edit any file reboot and the edits are undone that means your SDCard has gone read-only and needs to be replaced.