# Creating a blank SSH file gives output touch: ssh: Read-only file system

Tags: ssh

For the past few month I have been unable to use my raspberry pi because of a HDMI problem. I have tried following this guide:https://howtoraspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-hdmi-not-working/
Only to realise I have to enable SSH first. I then got out my microSD to SD card and put it in my Mac.

I then opened up terminal and did the following commands:
`cd /Volumes/boot` and then `touch ssh` and was given the output `touch: ssh: Read-only file system` . I then read this article: [Raspberry PI config.txt gets recreated and the custom modifications ignored](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98848/raspberry-pi-config-txt-gets-recreated-and-the-custom-modifications-ignored)

Does this mean that my microSD card is worn out or is something else wrong?

**Additional Info**

**Computer Software**: Mac OS X

**micro SD card**: NOOBS (Although I might have accidentally reformatted it and installed a new OS)

**SD Card Partitions**: boot and RECOVERY

**Raspberry Pi Model**: Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+

**diskutil list output**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            81.8 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                522.7 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.1 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_16 RECOVERY                1.3 GB     disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         33.6 MB    disk2s5
   3:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    69.2 MB    disk2s6
   4:                      Linux                         14.7 GB    disk2s7
```

**EDIT**: 
I have also now changed `config.txt` by uncommenting `#hdmi_force_hotplug=1` and
`#hdmi_drive=2`
(This was done without SSH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a few more article I and checking my adaptor I realised that it was just that the switch (which until a few seconds ago I had no idea what it did) was causing the boot file to be read-only

**EDIT**: 
1. This fixed the read only problem but as soon as I put the microSD in my RPI the SSH file was deleted.

2. IN the end I ended up reformatting the SD and installing Raspbian Stretch and enable `ssh` via `sudo raspi-config`

Comment: You probably have other problems. The advice on creating a ssh file applies to Raspbian. NOOBS has a different partition structure and frankly is unsuitable for headless boot. The Raspbian boot parition is NOT the 1st partition on the SD Card.

Comment: @Milliways So what else would be needed to be done?
I also changed `#hdmi_force_hotplug=1
#hdmi_drive=2` and un-commented them without SSH. Is this a problem?

Comment: I am not sure that creating a `ssh` file would even work, but if it does it would need to be in the correct partition - include the output of `diskutil list` in your question.

Comment: @Milliways Using `cd /Volumes/boot` and `touch ssh` it created a Unix Executable.I also changed #hdmi_force_hotplug=1 #hdmi_drive=2 and un-commented them without SSH. Is this a problem? I have also now included the output of `diskutil list` in the question.

Comment: `disk2s6` (which is the 2nd extended partition) looks like the Raspbian boot partition so you have edited the correct files. `disk2s1` is the NOOBS boot partition. PS None of us use NOOBS (it wastes 1.3 GB of your SD Card) and it appears to have changed in how it labels partitions since I last tried.

Comment: Ok. So does this mean that I have done the `ssh` file right? Also it is fine I edited `config.txt` without SSH. I just edited the file using TextEdit and uncommented `#hdmi_force_hotplug=1` and `#hdmi_drive=2` even though the article I read said to do it via SSH. PS My mum bought my RPI as a gift in 2015 and the NOOBS microSD card came with it. Thanks for the info.